# Vue Component, assign computed property to data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, computed-properties

i'm trying to set a component's data to a computed property value, as this fetches some localStorage data and manipulates it slightly.

I would then once the component is mounted listen for changes within the localStorage, and if my key is updated then fetch this value again, run it through my computed property and pass it back to the view.

However i'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: ids is not defined
    at a.render (vue.js:4)
    at a.e._render (vue:6)
    at a.r (vue:6)
    at un.get (vue:6)
    at new un (vue:6)
    at vue:6
    at a.bn.$mount (vue:6)
    at a.bn.$mount (vue:6)
    at init (vue:6)
    at vue:6
```

This is my component:

```
Vue.component('favourites-button', {
    render() {
        return this.$scopedSlots.default({
            count: this.ids.length
        });
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            ids: this.getFavourites()
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const self = this;
        Event.listen('favourites-updated', function (event) {
            console.log('updated external');
        });
        window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
            if (e.key === 'favourites') {
                console.log('updated');
                self.ids = self.getFavourites();
            }
        });
    },
    methods: {
        getFavourites: function() {
            let favourites = localStorage.getItem('favourites');
            return favourites.split(',').filter(id => !!id);
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

Updated my code, getting the same error however when the `storage` change event is fired.

**Edit 2:**

Turns out my template was expecting `toggle` within my scope but I removed this from my `$scopedSlots`.

Comment: You're using `this` inside the callback but it does not have the correct context.

Comment: Crap, completely forgot about that!

Comment: Updated my code and still has same issue, updated post

Comment: You got the exact same error even with the changes?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant see updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties work on data/props, so you can’t use them in data itself.

Instead, just set the default value of the data key to what’s in local storage:

```js
data: function () {
    return {
        ids: function() {
            let favourites = localStorage.getItem('favourites');
            return favourites.split(',').filter(id => !!id);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You [can use computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) for this, but you'd have to define a getter and a setter.

```
computed: {
  fullName: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return localStorage.getItem('favourites')
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      localStorage.setItem('favourites', newValue)
    }
  }
}
```

Much cleaner imo than using the mounted callback, setting data and then watching for changes.

Comment: What about when the local storage is updated, how would this update? I need to assign an event listener.

Comment: Is the localStorage updated 'outside' of vue? e.g. by some external script?

Comment: Nope, it's all within Vue and it's components

Comment: Then there is no need to watch for the `storage` event!